# Remove certain values from xml string if checkbox clicked

Tags: jquery

I have form that builds an xml string of all the values (excluding some) in the submitHandler of an .ajax submitted form to a WCF service, here is an example:

```
function SetServices() {        
    var services = '<SERVICE><SERVICECD>1KNTK</SERVICECD></SERVICE>';
$(":checked:not([name='ServiceType'], #Standard, #NoneForex, #RTT, #PRN, #BW, #Metrics, #STATUS :input, #EX_AGREEMENTS :input, #final_step :input)").each(function() {
services += '<SERVICE><SERVICECD>' + this.id + '</SERVICECD></SERVICE>';
});
$('#SERVICES').val('<SERVICES>' + services + '</SERVICES>');            
}
SetServices();
```

I need to add a function that will remove some values (var dontsubmit = ("#id1, #id2") etc if a checkbox ("#CME") is checked how would I combine this with the function "SetServices" or do I just run it after in the submitHandler?

```
$("#CME").change (function() {
    var dontsubmit = ("#id1, #id2, #id3, #id4, #id5");
    if ($(this).is(":checked") && dontsubmit.is(":checked") {
    $(this).remove(dontsubmit);
});
```

this isnt working, I need to figure out how to remove from the string "SetServices" builds.

Answer (score 1):

I would change you function to be:

```
function SetServices() {        
    var services = '<SERVICE><SERVICECD>1KNTK</SERVICECD></SERVICE>';
$(":checked:not([name='ServiceType'], #Standard, #NoneForex, #RTT, #PRN, #BW, #Metrics, #STATUS :input, #EX_AGREEMENTS :input, #final_step :input)").each(function() {
  if ($("#CME").is(":checked") ) 
{
    switch ( this.id) {
        case "id1", "id2", "id3":
           break;
        default:
           services += '<SERVICE><SERVICECD>' + this.id + '</SERVICECD></SERVICE>'; 
            break;
    }
    }
else {
   services += '<SERVICE><SERVICECD>' + this.id + '</SERVICECD></SERVICE>';
}


});
$('#SERVICES').val('<SERVICES>' + services + '</SERVICES>');            
}
SetServices();
```

Comment: @Avitus - not familiar with "case" Ill give it a go and see if it works. thanks for the help!

Comment: it's a switch statement in javascript.

Comment: @Avitus - where you have case "id1", "id2" do they not need "#id1", "#id2" ? trying to wrap my head around this...

Comment: it just has to be whatever this.id is to block the adding to the string.  i would alert it and see what it is.  here's a reference on switch http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: @Avitus - when I check all of the "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5" at the same time they are still submitted, if I do only one it isn't.

Comment: @Avitus - i was wrong, it's not working at all. if "CME" is checked do not include any of the checkboxes "id1", "id2" etc...